# Execute iteratively gradle command

Tags: bash, csv, gradle, build

I'm trying to run this script that reads the names of some projects downloaded by github from a csv file and for each of them it runs "gradle init" and "gradle build".

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    IFS=',' read -r -a array <<< "$line"
    linkRepo=${array[0]}
    nameRepo=${array[1]}
    shaCommit=${array[2]}
    moduleName=${array[3]}
    testName=${array[4]}
    cd $REPOSFOLDER
    cd $nameRepo
    gradle init
    message=$(gradle build)
    if echo "$message" |  grep -q "$TOSEARCH"; then
      OUTPUTBUILD="SUCCESS"
    else
      OUTPUTBUILD="FAILURE"
    fi      
    echo "sono qui" $PWD
    echo $linkRepo,$nameRepo,$shaCommit,$moduleName,$testName,$OUTPUTBUILD >> "$BASEDIR""$CSVOUTPUTFIRSTSTEPGRADLE"".csv"   
    cd ../..
done < "$fileInput"
```

The script only works for the first line of CSV , in fact once the "gradle build" execution is finished it stops or goes idle.

Anybody know why?

Thanks

Comment: Try https://www.shellcheck.net/  to validate your script. comeback here for more questions.

Comment: Try to replace all `gradle` with `</dev/null gradle`.

Comment: Since you're using gradle, why not just do this in a gradle script? Much nicer coding in groovy than bash